# Patterns in encrypted data

Tags: encryption

I often get to see encrypted data in databases and find it surprising how often obvious patterns are present. Training suggests that encryption is an attempt to introduce removable random noise into the data to make it difficult to discern the real data, yet the patterns are obvious.

Are there conclusions one could draw from the patterns? If all the data start with similar values is there a known mistake being made?

Here are some examples of some real encrypted data. Each entry seems to start with the same encoding. The "..." means that from here on it is seemingly random.

> D8B0867B1E3095CBEE21D86E8710E8978690026328CD555D10A9A9F587F1631C493EBC9F2AC0277FFD7CD2C22D22B875F4983E2E49B18CB224...
>   D8B0867B1E3095CBEE21D86E8710E8978690026328CD555D10A9A9F587F1631C493EBC9F2AC0277FFD7CD2C22D22B875F4983E2E49B18CB224...
>   D8B0867B1E3095CBEE21D86E8710E8978690026328CD555D10A9A9F587F1631C493EBC9F2AC0277FFD7CD2C22D22B875F4983E2E49B18CB244...
>   D8B0867B1E3095CBEE21D86E8710E8978690026328CD555D10A9A9F587F1631C493EBC9F2AC0277FFD7CD2C22D22B875F4983E2E49B18CB292...
>   D8B0867B1E3095CBEE21D86E8710E8978690026328CD555D10A9A9F587F1631C493EBC9F2AC0277FFD7CD2C22D22B875F4983E2E49B18CB292...

Comment: What are you using to generate this data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. It's unencrypted metadata, for example string length, encoding, algorithm used, hash etc., followed by the actual, encrypted data which is practically completely random.
2. It's the same data encrypted with the same key in all cases, at least for the first hundred bytes or so, and the encryption algorithm doesn't use a [stream cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_cipher), whereby (for example) a chunk of data of random bits is XOR-ed with the first chunk of the plaintext before encryption, which is then XOR-ed with the next chunk of the plaintext before encryption etc. The initial random chunk is then prepended to the result so that the decryptor knows how to start.

If it's 1), no conclusions can be drawn *à priori*. But the metadata might conceivably yield hints, e.g. one might know that the cleartext always begins with some specific integer.

If it's 2), then the attacker knows at least that all your messages start the same way and are all encrypted using the same key. This may or may not be helpful for further analysis. As the same key is being consistently used, crypto gurus will immediately think of applying [differential cryptanalysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_attack).

Comment: +1 with "not using a stream cipher" being the "known mistake" asked for in the question :-) With SQL databases, using a stream cipher might be impossible if you need foreign key relations.

Comment: And if I was really devious, I'd fill my database with some sample data that is encoded poorly for crackers to find. A Google query would then notify me when someone successfully attacked me and published the results somewhere. If I change this data every day, I could even narrow the time frame of the attack.